# SQL Server : aggregate function doesn't work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I have imported a price list from a csv to my SQL Server database. That has worked fine. But now some weird stuff. Table is named `PRICE` which includes a column (and some more) `Endprice` and a total of 761 rows. All datatypes are `varchar(50)`.

```
SELECT MAX(Endprice) 
FROM PRICE
```

When I want this simple SQL statement to show the highest price in the column, I get a wrong result. I don't know why.

I get 98,39 as a result, but that's definitively wrong, it must be 100,73.

Here you can see a part of the data:

[image: Here u can see a part of the data]

And now the wrong `MAX()` result:

[image]

BUT when I'm using the `MIN` function I get the highest one!? The min is somewhere at ~50 (not shown in the screenshot part).

[image]`

The resultset of `SELECT Endprice FROM PRICE` is correct. I am at my wit's end.

Comment: Your problem is `Endprice` is varchar(50), therefore it is comparing strings not numbers, which means that a 9>1 no matter what cames next. You have to convert it to a number before the max!

Comment: Never, ever store numbers as `varchar` - you have just learned one of the reasons why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! I have overseen this at the import wizard. But i also had thoght that internaly this string is interpreted as a intetger. With datatype money, it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your column is a varchar, so it is determining the min or max based on characters.  The column should be a decimal or money type, so it sorts by the value of your number (instead of an alphabetic sort like you are getting now).

Alphabetic sort: 9 is more than 1, thus 98.39 is the max.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because price is a `varchar()`.

Here are two solutions:

```
order by len(price), price
```

This works assuming that all the price values have the same structure.

Or:

```
order by cast(price as float)
```

If you could have non-numeric values (always a danger when storing numbers in the wrong data type):

```
order by (case when isnumeric(price) = 1 then cast(price as float) end)
```

Or better yet:

```
alter table alter column price money
```

Then you don't have to worry about having the wrong type for the column.

Comment: I have change it to money :). Is there a way to automatically add the currency sign?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `Endprice` columns is `varchar(50)`, therefore it is comparing strings not numbers, which means that a 9>1 no matter what cames next of the first digit. You have to convert it to a number before the max!

**Also you really should consider in doing what  @a_horse_with_no_name suggested change your column into a number like column type.**

This is a example on how you solve your actual problem

```
select max(cast(endprice as money)) from sample
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/767f6/1

Note that I used `.` as a decimal separator it will depend on your database language setup.